# How do Object.freeze() and Readonly work in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
class C {
  private x: string = "";
}

interface I {
  x: string;
}

const a: C = Object.freeze(new C()); // Error: Property 'x' is missing in type 'Readonly<C>' but required in type 'C'.
const b: Readonly<C> = Object.freeze(new C());
const c: I = Object.freeze(new C()); // Error: Property 'x' is missing in type 'Readonly<C>' but required in type 'I'.
const d: I = Object.freeze({ x: "hi" });
d.x = "foo";
```

Why do I get errors on those lines and not on the others? It almost makes sense that `Readonly<T>` is distinct from `T` and `Object.freeze()` returns `Readonly<T>`, except that the last two lines compile fine.

Comment: Looks like `private` is an issue, when you remove it all lines are correct

Comment: Ah maybe `Readonly<>` only works on public fields?

Comment: yep, it is how mapped types work. you can check that: `type T1 = Readonly<C> // {}`